# Мониторинг работы PHP-скрипта

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Здравствуйте. Имеется PHP-скрипт, за выполнением которого я хотел бы следить во время его работы. То есть функция выполняется, посылает отчет, продолжает работу, а я в это время наблюдаю этот отчет на html-страничке.

Решил, что попробую совместить PHP с AJAX. Получилось что-то вроде этого:

**ajax.js**

```
function go() {

    var req = getXmlHttp()
    var statusElem = document.getElementById('status') 

    req.onreadystatechange = function() {  
        if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
            statusElem.innerHTML = req.responseText
        }
    }

    req.open('GET', '/script.php', true);  
    req.send(null);

    statusElem.innerHTML = 'Ожидаю ответа сервера...' 
}
```

**script.php**

```
<?php
    $somearrays = array('1', '2', '3');
    foreach($somearrays as $somearray) {
        sleep(3);
        echo $somearray;
    }
?>
```

Недолго думая, я нажал на кнопочку и стал ждать каждые 3 секунды новый "отчет". Но не тут-то было. Спустя 3 секунды не пришел ни один "отчет", но за-то они все пришли через 9 секунд, что меня не очень-то обрадовало.

**Вопрос:** Как циклично получать результаты выполнения функций в цикле во время его работы?

Comment: Попробуйте явно закрывать сессию перед `sleep()` (функцию не помню, но вы ее быстро найдете). Скорее всего, это блокировка сессий.

Comment: надо буфер убрать и в php и в webserver.

Comment: В общем я не до конца понял все ниже перечисленные ответы, но узнав из некоторых что можно запускать PHP-скрипты через командную строку и следить за ее выполнением, я решил попробовать через SSH и все заработало. Спасибо за ответы. Не могу определить какой из них лучший, пусть каждый сам выберет для себя подходящий ответ.

Answer (score 2):

GET /script.php вообще-то нельзя назвать "слежением за работой". Это вызов нового процесса.
Ответ приходит только по окончании работы веб-скрипта — это нормальное поведение.

Насколько я понимаю изначальную задачу, надо иметь некий долгоживущий процесс на сервере (CLI, а не CGI) и смотреть чего он там наработал. Рекомендую писать результаты скрипта в лог-файл, а веб-монитором по таймеру этот лог читать. То есть нужны 3 компонента:

- сам CLI-скрипт, пишуший в лог;
- серверная часть монитора, которая умеет читать лог с указанного места;
- клиентский монитор, который шлет задание на сервер и визуализирует ответ.

Гуглите сочетание "php web tail".

Answer (score 0):

Если говорить о проблеме "выплевывает все сразу по завершении работы скрипта", то она известная и решается просто:

1. Выставить `output_buffering` в 0
2. Проверить, выставилось ли.
3. Перед этим кодом дописать `ob_implicit_flush(true);`

Я только не понимаю, зачем здесь городить АЯКС, и почему нельзя обратиться к скрипту напрямую.

Но если говорить о данном конкретном случае, сама идея мониторить "долгоиграющие" скрипты через браузер - не слишком, мягко говоря, удачная.

Учитесь использовать стандартные инструменты веб-программиста - консоль и запуск  скриптов в CLI-режиме. Тут вам будет  логирование, и независимость от капризов браузеров, и удобный вывод, и простой перевод этих скриптов в крон и ещё миллион причин по которым ни один веб-программист в здравом уме не занимается подобным "мониторингом" через браузер.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, но я не совсем понимаю эту логику: запускать PHP-скрипты "на себе" через командную строку и при этом взаимодействовать с сайтом на сервере. Можете кратко объяснить или направить на какой-нибудь толковый гайд?